# Syntax error (missing operator) when link to Excel, query runs ok

Tags: excel, ms-access, syntax, operator-keyword

I'm building this database in MS Access and created this query, it runs ok in Access, but prompt this error message only when I tried to link/source data from Excel to it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Combined Risk - Current Mth].DUNS, 
    [Combined Risk - Current Mth].[Name Supplied], 
    [Combined Risk - Current Mth].[Combined Risk Rating], 
    [Combined Risk - Previous Mth].[Combined Risk Rating], 
    [Combined Risk - 4th Mth].[Combined Risk Rating], 
    [Combined Risk - 3rd Mth].[Combined Risk Rating], 
    [Combined Risk - 2nd Mth].[Combined Risk Rating], 
    [Combined Risk - 1st Mth].[Combined Risk Rating]
FROM (((([Combined Risk - Current Mth] 
LEFT JOIN [Combined Risk - 4th Mth] ON [Combined Risk - Current Mth].DUNS = [Combined Risk - 4th Mth].DUNS) 
LEFT JOIN [Combined Risk - 3rd Mth] ON [Combined Risk - Current Mth].DUNS = [Combined Risk - 3rd Mth].DUNS) 
LEFT JOIN [Combined Risk - 2nd Mth] ON [Combined Risk - Current Mth].DUNS = [Combined Risk - 2nd Mth].DUNS) 
LEFT JOIN [Combined Risk - 1st Mth] ON [Combined Risk - Current Mth].DUNS = [Combined Risk - 1st Mth].DUNS) 
LEFT JOIN [Combined Risk - Previous Mth] ON [Combined Risk - Current Mth].DUNS = [Combined Risk - Previous Mth].DUNS;
```

Any help would be really appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: try tagging it with access...  you may get more response from people with experience linking into access from excel

Comment: perhaps the column names need to be unique?  try aliasing the six [Combined Risk Rating] columns in your select list to six unique names

Comment: Thanks dav1dsm1th, once I alias the field names it worked! Thank you!!!

Comment: glad to hear you have solved the problem

Comment: I am happy for the solution, but I anticipate future troubles as I look at that query and imagine the tables underneath.  Suggest some studying on the topic of good database design.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by multiple columns having the same name.  Alias those columns to solve the issue:-

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Combined Risk - Current Mth].DUNS, 
    [Combined Risk - Current Mth].[Name Supplied], 
    [Combined Risk - Current Mth].[Combined Risk Rating] as CRR_current, 
    [Combined Risk - Previous Mth].[Combined Risk Rating] as CRR_previous, 
    [Combined Risk - 4th Mth].[Combined Risk Rating] as CRR_4th, 
    [Combined Risk - 3rd Mth].[Combined Risk Rating] as CRR_3rd, 
    [Combined Risk - 2nd Mth].[Combined Risk Rating] as CRR_2nd, 
    [Combined Risk - 1st Mth].[Combined Risk Rating] as CRR_1st
FROM (((([Combined Risk - Current Mth] 
LEFT JOIN [Combined Risk - 4th Mth] ON [Combined Risk - Current Mth].DUNS = [Combined Risk - 4th Mth].DUNS) 
LEFT JOIN [Combined Risk - 3rd Mth] ON [Combined Risk - Current Mth].DUNS = [Combined Risk - 3rd Mth].DUNS) 
LEFT JOIN [Combined Risk - 2nd Mth] ON [Combined Risk - Current Mth].DUNS = [Combined Risk - 2nd Mth].DUNS) 
LEFT JOIN [Combined Risk - 1st Mth] ON [Combined Risk - Current Mth].DUNS = [Combined Risk - 1st Mth].DUNS) 
LEFT JOIN [Combined Risk - Previous Mth] ON [Combined Risk - Current Mth].DUNS = [Combined Risk - Previous Mth].DUNS;
```